# How avoid that when keyboard appear move the layout up in SwiftUI?

Tags: layout, swiftui, keyboard

My question is: how to avoid when the keyboard appears it moves the layout up?

I want to keep it in the same position all the time, as well when the keyboard appears.

In the graphic: **Img 1** you can see the view.

In the graphic: **Img 2** you can see the problem. The view is moved up.

In the graphic: **Img 3** you can see what I want, I want to reduce the size of the view, but not move the entire layout up.

[image: Image description]

```
 var body: some View {
        
        ZStack (alignment: .bottom) {
           VStack {
                FormatView(titulo: “Titel here”) 
                    .overlay(
                        VStack (spacing: 3){
                            Color.clear.frame(height: 44)

                            InPutTextField(dataTextFild: $DatoS.InPutTextField, isTextFildActiv: $DatoS.keyBoardOn, horizontalPadding: 120) // TextFiel view (String, Bool,CGflou)
                            
                          Image(“xImagen”)
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: screenSize.maxX - 140, height: 256)
                             .overlay(
                                    Text(“\(DatoS.outPutText)”)
                                )

                                
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    )
                Spacer()
                ZStack (alignment: .bottom){
                    if DatoS.actualView != .homeTwo && actualView != .homeThree {
                        MenuHomeTwo()
                            .frame(width: screenSize.maxX - 40)
                            .offset(y: screenSize.maxY > 738 ? -82 : -62)
                            .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                            .animation(.easeInOut)
                    }
                    MenuHomeInferior()
                    
                }
            }
            
            
        } .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color("backgroundColor1”))
         .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest adding to your question the code that you have tried already. That way people may be more inclined to help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64421124/12299030? or https://stackoverflow.com/a/64292661/12299030?

Comment: @Andrew posted thx!!.

Comment: @Asperi I already tried both options and neither of them works as I hope.

Comment: Thank you all very much! I finally found a solution that works perfectly for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64016326/14675797